# What are HTTP headers and what they meant for?

Tags: node.js, rest, api, http, http-headers

I am developing REST API with Node.js, which is about to handle requests from remote and serve them.

Depend of requests types I can have the data using the  `req.body` or `req.params` methods.

That means I can pass all the data I need through those methods, that could be strings, objects arrays and etc...

Headers are created by some reason and that probably have a good one.

I know I can pass headers to the request too, and have them like this:

```
let authorization = req.headers['authorization'];
```

I can access the data without the headers, like auth token;
so why headers are made first of all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP headers are the set of useful information. Basically, Headers are meant to provide additional information to client and server when they are communicating with request and response. It contains all information like port no, protocols, etc. These type of information seems useful in some applications for different checks. Headers are of different type you can check it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers

Answer (score 1):

> What are HTTP headers and what they meant for?

See [RFC-7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231)

> [Request Header Fields](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5)
>
> A client sends request header fields to provide more information about the request context, make the request conditional based on the target resource state, suggest preferred formats for the response, supply authentication credentials, or modify the expected request processing.  These fields act as request modifiers, similar to the parameters on a programming language method invocation.
>
> [Response Header Fields](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7)
>
> The response header fields allow the server to pass additional information about the response beyond what is placed in the status-line.  These header fields give information about the server, about further access to the target resource, or about related resources.